# Can not totally remove ROS

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS once before and then removed it, probably the wrong way.
Now I've been trying to install other software packages but I had the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to remove ROS completely by following [these commands](http://answers.ros.org/question/57213/how-i-completely-remove-all-ros-from-my-system/) but it didn't work.

I tried reinstalling ROS following [these constructions](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu) but I had the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package ros-kinetic-desktop-full (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials
 ros-kinetic-common-tutorials
 ros-kinetic-desktop
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I totally remove it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265359/can-not-totally-remove-ros/) by [SalahuddinAsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31008/salahuddinash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This worked for me

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials
```

Got it from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/919983/681275)

---

Originally posted by [SalahuddinAsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31008/salahuddinash/) with karma: 16 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0